# Use variable with string (with spaces) as value in grep

Tags: bash, shell

My variable $pepe has the name of a file (with spaces) as value, and I want to use the grep command to find that file in ls -l. The problem is that I can literally write it but I cannot use it if its set inside $pepe.

In the image you can see what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You must duble quote and use interpolation in this case:

`ls -l | grep echo "${pepe}"`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
ls -l | grep "`echo ${pepe}`"
```

This worked for me.